# Obtener valores de array dentro de otro array PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo dos array los cuales contienen el mismo numero de valores cada uno. Uno contiene el `id` de `materia` y el otro `calificaciones`.

Necesito acceder a las calificaciones para posteriormente ingresarlas en una base de datos. El problema es que puedo acceder a las materias con un ciclo `for`. Pero como puedo acceder a las calificaciones dentro del mismo ciclo.

Este es mi codigo, trate con otro ciclo `for` dentro pero no hace lo que deseo.

```
<?php
//require('../../../php/cone.php');

$id = $_POST['id'];
$matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
$periodo = $_POST['periodo'];
$calificacion = $_POST['calificacion'];  //Esto es un array
$materia = $_POST['materia'];            //Esto es un array


//Recorro todos los elementos que hay en materia
for ($i=0;$i<count($materia);$i++)
      {

      //saco el valor de cada elemento
      echo "Materia: ".$materia[$i]."";

      //Aqui necesito acceder al array que esta en la variable materia.
      //Intente con otro ciclo for dentro pero no hace lo que deseo.
      echo "Calificacion: ".$calificacion."";
      echo "<br>";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según los detalles que das, ambos arrays tienen el mismo número de datos, entonces, asumiendo que estén ordenados en el orden correspondiente (Posición 0 de materia corresponde a posición 0 de calificación), basta con usar el mismo index para referenciar la llave en ambos arrays:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($materia); $i++) {

  echo "Materia: " . $materia[$i] . "";

  echo "Calificacion: " . $calificacion[$i] . "";

  echo "<br>";

}
```

Comment: No pense que fuera tan facil. Gracias Shaz ya lo probe y funciona como lo quiero. :D

Answer (score 3):

otra forma de hacerlo, y suponiendo que la clave del array de materias corresponde también a un valor en el array de calificaciones es la siguiente:

```
foreach ($materia as $key => $value) {
  echo "Materia: " . $value . " ";
  echo "Calificación: " . $calificacion[$key] . " ";
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Aquí estarías usando una estructura que itera sobre cada elemento del array, devolviendo la clave y el valor de cada "vuelta".

Comment: Gracias Muriano vere cual es mas conveniente usar :D